# Check when filter is done, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter with a lot of logic combined with much data. It takes a few seconds until it's done. I want to display a loading symbol that indicates the filter is working.

I tried this:

I have ng-show on my loading symbol in my markup. I turn on the property in the beginning in my filter and then turn it off at the end.

It's not working. The property never get set to true. Is there any better approach to this?

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .filter('matchPositions', function ($filter, CommonFactory) {
    return function (actions, firstLevels, secondLevels, objectTypes, searchText) {
      var filtered = [];

      CommonFactory.filterLoading = true;

      //logic here

      CommonFactory.filterLoading = false;
      return filtered;
    };
  });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('ActionStateCtrl', function($scope, CommonFactory){
    $scope.filterLoading = CommonFactory.filterLoading;
});
```

Markup

```
<i ng-show="filterLoading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```

Comment: filters are synchronous  functions, meaning you can not update the scope at the beginning and the end of the filter function because the digest will not run until you exit the filter. Unfortunately you can not return a promise either. Instead of using a filter, do the heavy lifting in the controller (or better yet, a service), and when the data is ready set it to the scope.

Comment: filters run very often, i dont think its a good idea to run a filter which takes several seconds (and freezing the ui)

Comment: @YairTavor So if I just copy my code to a service instead and use the same approach with setting the loading value at the beginning and end of the function it will work?

Comment: I'm posting an answer with code examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filters are synchronous functions, meaning you can not update the scope at the beginning and the end of the filter function because the digest will not run until you exit the filter. Unfortunately you can not return a promise either. Instead of using a filter, do the heavy lifting in the controller (or better yet, a service), and when the data is ready set it to the scope:

```
app.service('myService', function($q, $timeout){
    return {
        // this function is async and heavy
        getData : = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function(){ deferred.resolve('Result Here!'); }, 5000);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.loading = true;

   myService.getData().then(function(results){
         $scope.showThisData = results;
         $scope.loading = false;
   });
});
```

Then You can do in you html

```
<div ng-if="!loading"> {{ showThisData }} </div>
<div ng-if="loading"> Loading, please wait... </div>
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TcQtY8e6phLTQ4oZcHPn?p=preview